# How to write a large number of records to an Xodus database without memory leaks?

Tags: kotlin, xodus

I need to insert around 150M records into an Xodus database using xodus-dnq in a batch. Based on examples, I have implemented the following method:

```
        XdModel.registerNodes(
                XDTrip
        )
        val store = StaticStoreContainer.init(
                dbFolder = File(target),
                environmentName = "trips"
        )
        initMetaData(XdModel.hierarchy, store)
        store.use { store ->
            store.persistentStore.use {
                // TripLoader(File(src)) returns a stream with roughly 150M elements
                TripLoader(File(src)).forEach { databaseTrip ->
                    store.transactional {
                        XDTrip.new {
                            id = databaseTrip.id
                            start = databaseTrip.start.epochSecond
                            end = databaseTrip.end.epochSecond
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

This works fine but leaks memory. Presumably I need to manually commit/flush/persist the transaction?

Based on another suggestion I have refactored this to run smaller batches within a transaction:

```
    XdModel.registerNodes(
            XDTrip,
            XDPosition,
            XDPositionSource
    )
    val store = StaticStoreContainer.init(
            dbFolder = File(target),
            environmentName = "trips"
    )
    initMetaData(XdModel.hierarchy, store)
    store.use {
        it.use { store ->
            Sequence { TripLoader(File(src)).iterator() }.chunked(100).forEachIndexed { index, csvChunk ->
                store.transactional {
                    println("Chunk $index")
                    csvChunk.forEach { csvTrip ->
                        XDTrip.new {
                            id = csvTrip.id
                            start = csvTrip.start.epochSecond
                            end = csvTrip.end.epochSecond
                            // ...
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This however still leaks memory.

I analysed the memory and found an instance of `jetbrains.exodus.core.dataStructures.ConcurrentLongObjectCache` taking up most of the heap:

> One instance of
>   "jetbrains.exodus.core.dataStructures.ConcurrentLongObjectCache"
>   loaded by "sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader @ 0x4c0481d58" occupies
>   45,075,952 (80.24%) bytes. The memory is accumulated in one instance
>   of
>   "jetbrains.exodus.core.dataStructures.ConcurrentLongObjectCache$CacheEntry[]"
>   loaded by "sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader @ 0x4c0481d58".
>
> Keywords
>   jetbrains.exodus.core.dataStructures.ConcurrentLongObjectCache
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader @ 0x4c0481d58
>   jetbrains.exodus.core.dataStructures.ConcurrentLongObjectCache$CacheEntry[]

I can see how the database size on disk increases while the program runs, so I'm unsure why the cache fills up here.

Answer (score 2):

Process heavy operations with batches is a recommended way to go. If you use Kotlin Sequences there is `windowed` extension function. So your code will be like:

```
TripLoader(File(src)).windowed(1000) { trips ->
                    store.transactional {
                    trips.forEach { databaseTrip ->
                        XDTrip.new {
                            id = databaseTrip.id
                            start = databaseTrip.start.epochSecond
                            end = databaseTrip.end.epochSecond
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Practically if you do something in runtime or whole operation consumes a lot of time it's better to go a bit deeper and use low-level api. Code will become more complex but runs times faster.

As an example if you believes that data is consistent and you do not need to check all constraints, relations and other you can use something like this:

```
val type =  XdTrip.entityType
TripLoader(File(src)).windowed(1000) { trips ->
        persistentStore.executeInExclusiveTransaction { txn -> 
               trips.forEach { databaseTrip ->
                        txn.newEntity(type).also {
                            it.setProperty("id", databaseTrip.id)
                            ...
                        }
               }
        }
```

Window size should checked according to imported data. In case of primitive data structures it can be increased.

Comment: Thanks @lehvolk that helps. Oddly, `store.transactional` is only present on a transient entity store which challenges me a bit when working with a persistentStore. But I'm sure I'll figure it out.

Comment: @mritz_p you are welcome. 

I've just miss, sorry. `persistentStore` is a reference from `store` to low-level api `PersistentEntityStore` instance. Take a look to `TransientEntityStore#persistentStore`.

Comment: Thanks @lehvolk. I'm struggling with going the other way around. I.e. I'd love to use the `store.transactional` API after loading a _persistent_ entity store (`PersistentEntityStores.newInstance(database)`). But in fairness that is a whole new question :-)

Comment: Apologies, @lehvolk but chunks/batches/windows actually do not seem to help here. I've added a modified code snippet to the original question.

Comment: @mritz_p could you please file an issue here https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/XD you can attach privately any code-snippets and examples of code. Seems you are facing with some corner-case or there are specific code hidden from your code snippets.

Comment: Thanks @lehvolk, I've created a bug: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/XD-803 The fact that it is so easy to reproduce really makes me wonder if I'm using the API wrong.